# i want to add data to firestore from edittext android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add data to firestore, but code is not performing as i want.

The document shows same thing as i'm doing and it is doing in other videos, but on my side only on failure listener is hitting even values are not null.

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var editTextName: EditText
private lateinit var editTextNumber: EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    editTextName = binding.nameEdtTxt
    editTextNumber = binding.numberEdtTxt


    binding.signup.setOnClickListener {

        val name = editTextName.text.toString()
        val number = editTextNumber.text.toString()
```

I toasted msg here for value value are responding here in variables but not adding to firestore:

```
        val hashMap = hashMapOf(
            "name" to name,
            "number" to number
        )
        db.collection("users").add(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
```

The only this thing is hitting is here:

```
            Toast.makeText(this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

    binding.txtAccount.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, loginInActivity::class.java))
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is any of the onSuccess or onFailure even triggered?

Comment: yes  onFailure even is triggered

Answer (score 0):

If a failure listener gets called, there is an exception. Log or throw that exception to find the root cause of your problem:

```
db.collection("users").add(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}.addOnFailureListener { exception -> // 
    Toast.makeText(this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.e("Firestore", "Creating document failed", exception) // 
}
```